# Is there an easy way to completely freeze object and its children in Javascript, (Deep Freeze)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Often you have to pass an object as parameter. Functions accessing those objects are pass by reference and can change original object. Which depending on situation can be  unwanted outcome. So is there a way to freeze object. I know about `Object.freeze()`

But it doesn't affect objects/arrays inside it.

For example

```
a = { arr: [1,2,3]}; 
Object.freeze(a);
a.arr.push(4); // still works
```

Comment: Have you tried to implement that (or find an implementation)? What happened?

Comment: I tried something with getter and setter but it doesn't scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a very simple recursive solution like so:

```js
let a = {
  arr: [1, 2, 3],
  name: "A. Bc"
};

const deepFreeze = o => {
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(o)) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof value == "object") {
      deepFreeze(value);
    }
  }
  Object.freeze(o);
  return o;
}

deepFreeze(a);

try {
  a.arr.push(4);
} catch(e) {
  console.log("Error: ", e);
}
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 3):

To deep-freeze all enumerable properties (ES2015+):

```
// Recursively freeze an object
const deepFreeze = x => {
  Object.freeze(x)
  Object.values(x).forEach(deepFreeze)
}
```

If you have circular references:

```
// Recursively freeze an object with circular references
const deepFreeze = x => {
  Object.freeze(x)
  Object.values(x).filter(x => !Object.isFrozen(x)).forEach(deepFreeze)
}
```

If you *also* have to deep-freeze any shallow-frozen stuff (slightly slower):

```
// Recursively deep freeze an object with circular references
const deepFreeze = (x, frozen = []) => {
  if (frozen.includes(x)) return null
  frozen.push(x)
  Object.freeze(x)
  Object.values(x).forEach(x => deepFreeze(x, frozen))
}
```

tldr; Two-liner:

```
const deepFreeze = (x, frozen = []) => frozen.includes(x) ||
  frozen.push(Object.freeze(x)) && Object.values(x).forEach(x => deepFreeze(x, frozen))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), there is a function there that suggests deepFreeze functionality however it is not stack safe. I personally have an ES5 version to async iterate. For ES6 something along these lines might work, I did not test it thoroughly though:

```
function deepFreeze(o,promises,oldestParent){
    promises = promises || [];
    oldestParent = oldestParent || o;
    promises.push(
        Promise.resolve().then(function(){
            Object.values(Object.freeze(o)).forEach(function(d,i){
                typeof d === "object" && deepFreeze(d,promises,oldestParent);
            });
            return oldestParent;
        })
    );
    return Promise.all(promises).then((a)=>a[0]);
}

var o = {a:3,b:{test:1,test2:2},c:1};
deepFreeze(o).then(function(x){console.log(x)}); //o is deep frozen
```

**Warning**: I assume your object's properties are enumerable, if not then use `getOwnPropertyNames` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
function deepFreeze(object) {

  // Retrieve the property names defined on object
  var propNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object);

  // Freeze properties before freezing self

  for (let name of propNames) {
    let value = object[name];

    object[name] = value && typeof value === "object" ? 
      deepFreeze(value) : value;
  }

  return Object.freeze(object);
}

let a = { arr: [1,2,3]}; 
deepFreeze(a);
a.arr.push(4); // TypeError: Cannot add property 3, object is not extensible
```

(second code [second gray area]) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze#What_is_shallow_freeze

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [`deep-freeze`](https://github.com/substack/deep-freeze) it does recursively `Object.freeze()` on objects

Here's how they implement it

```
function deepFreeze (o) {
  Object.freeze(o);

  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o).forEach(function (prop) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(prop)
    && o[prop] !== null
    && (typeof o[prop] === "object" || typeof o[prop] === "function")
    && !Object.isFrozen(o[prop])) {
      deepFreeze(o[prop]);
    }
  });

  return o;
};
```

Comment: No, don't use this, this is an example of everything that's wrong with nodejs ecosystem. An entire package even with a test, to save you from writing the simplest recursive for loop ever with two conditions.

Comment: i agree. i try to minimize external packages.

Comment: but why to reinvent the wheel, if there is something already done, just build on top of it.

Comment: I mean I'll copy paste this. but not be tied to external dependency that can be changed anytime.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a Proxy. Instead of deep freezing the object you get a proxy to the object that forbids writing:

```
const immutableProxy = o => {
  if (o===null || typeof o !== 'object') return o
  return new Proxy(o, {
    get(obj, prop) {
      return immutableProxy(obj[prop])
    },
    set(obj, prop) {
      throw new Error(`Can not set prop ${prop} on immutable object`)
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider [immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/). It's an excellent tool to create immutable Js data structures.

In your case, that would be:

```
const a = produce({ arr: [1,2,3] }, () => {})
```

The `() => {}` is necessary because `produce` expects a function that mutates the first param, but there is no mutation required here.

If you are trying to freeze a couple of data structures and won't use immutability otherwise, it might not be worth the cost of an extra third-party library. And the above solutions will be enough.